# How to pass a file as a parameter in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, file, ionic-framework, file-upload

I want to upload a local file with angular 
the file is already in the server and i dont want to get it from a form

```
  upload(url: string, file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', file);

    let params = new HttpParams();

    const options = {
      params: params,
      reportProgress: true,
    };

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, formData, options);
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

I'd like to pass the file as a parameter to the upload function whenever i call it.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: how pass the file that is stored in the server as a parameter to the upload function

Comment: if the file is already in server why do you need an upload function ?

Comment: to send it to another server